# pandas read_csv function fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert the following csv into a dataframe, using simply :

```
    import pandas as pd
    ticket = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

However, due to the missing quotation marks on the first column of the csv :

```
 A,"B","C","D"

 0,"1","2","3"
```

It fails to assign properly each rows to its rightful header.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv')

IN [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   A  "B"  "C"  "D"
0  0  "1"  "2"  "3"
```

Seems to work for me with the given data placed into a .csv, can you be more specific about the error?